# Diferencia entre bucles

Tags: javascript

Leyendo la documentación no logro entender la diferencia entre el bucle `for` y el bucle `while`.

Si for es:

```
for (var i = 0; i < condicion; i++){...}
```

- Declaras el bucle
- Declaras i con valor 0
- Mientras que i sea menor que la condición (un lenght, o lo que fuere)
- i suma +1
- Con cada iteración del bucle, realiza el código metido entre llaves {}

El bucle while me parece igual:

```
x = 0;
y = condición;
while (x < y) {...}
```

- Declaramos x como valor 0 e y como la condición
- Mientras que x es menor que y
- Ejecuta el código dentro de las llaves {}

Quizá esté entendiendo yo algo mal, pero ¿alguien podría clarificarme las diferencias entre uno y otro?

Comment: ninguna, pero de las ningunas.. lo que pasa es que una es mas flexible que otra en cuanto a lo que iteras.. si tu iteracion no es sobre un valor numerico, un for no sirve de mucho...

Comment: Y un while? sobre qué otra cosa que no sea un valor numérico puede hacerse la iteración?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que ambos sirven para lo mismo, porque ambos son ciclos, y en cierto sentido varios de los ciclos se parecen, no solo el `for` y el `while` si no tambien la variacion `do-while`.

La diferencia entonces entre el ciclo `for` y el ciclo `while` es en el para que lo vas a **usar**, es decir, **que necesitas hacer** y de qué partes.

Tambien hay que tener en cuenta que un ciclo `while` enrealidad solo requiere de una condicion para ejecutarse o terminar.

Por lo que cosas como estas son totalmente validas:

```
while(true) {...}
```

OJO!, no vayas a intentar ejecutarlo que se te cuelga el navegador.

ya otra cosa seria que cambiaras la condicion con la que se ejecuta el ciclo while para que esta de `false` y deje de ejecutarse:

```
let x = 0;

while(x < 1){
   x++;
}
```

Que aunque esta condicion tiene mucho en comun con las partes de un ciclo `for` no podemos decir que son exactamente lo mismo, pues en un ciclo `while` **no puedes** definir el `iterador` al mismo tiempo que la `condicion de terminacion` del ciclo ni tampoco su `incremento` o `decremento`.

Por lo que este segundo ejemplo enrealidad podriamos verlo como la simulacion de un ciclo `for` usando un ciclo `while`.

Mientras que en un ciclo `for`:

```
for(let i = 0; i < 1; i++){
   
}
```

Siempre vamos a tener 3 elementos en orden separados por coma:

- Inicializacion de iterador
- Condicion de escape
- Operacion para alcanzar la condicion de escape

En este sentido ya podriamos ver una ligera diferencia entre el ciclo `for` y el ciclo `while`.

De todas maneras te dejare unas pequenas pistas sobre cuando se usa un ciclo `for` y cuando un ciclo `while`.

**Cuando se usa un ciclo for?**

El ciclo `for` normalmente es usado cuando sabemos el numero de iteraciones exactas que queremos realizar, por ejemplo para iterar un arreglo podemos usar un ciclo `for` y es lo mas comun.

**Cuando se usa un ciclo while?**

Se usa un ciclo `while` cuando no sabes el numero exacto de iteraciones que tienes que realizar, o muchas veces se usa cuando quieres crear ciclos infinitos controlados, tambien se usa en caso de que la condicion del ciclo no dependa de un iterador numerico.

Comment: Me has suscitado mas dudas fijate.
1º.- Dices que el ciclo WHILE se usa cuando no sabes el número exacto de iteraciones. Hasta ahora con lo que he andado con programación siempre he necesitado saber dicho número. ¿Podrías ponerme un ejemplo?

2º.- ¿Qué es un ciclo infinito controlado?

Comment: @AQMR ya edito la respuesta para responder a tus dudas

Answer (score 1):

La principal diferencia entre ellos es que con el **for** conoces el numero de iteraciones que tendrá tu bucle, mientras que con el **while** no siempre sabes la cantidad exacta, sino que durante la ejecución de mismo, la condición que mantiene **while** deberá activarse y el bucle dejara de ejecutarse.

En muchos casos, ambas formas pueden ser utilizadas quedando a criterio del desarrollador como emplear uno o el otro.

Por ejemplo en el **for**, tienes el valor de i = 0 y el valor de la variable condición debe ser un numero entero.

```
for (var i = 0; i < condicion; i++){...}
```

Así el **for** antes de comenzar a ejecutarse, sabrá la cantidad de iteraciones que estará ejecutado.

En el caso del **while**, no necesariamente debes saber la cantidad de iteraciones que tendrá el bucle, si por ejemplo la condición es que se ejecute mientras la variable encontrado = false

```
while (encontrado == false) 
{... Deberá indicarse una condición que haga que encontrado = true  }
```

Esta condición de **while** posibilita a que si no se establece una condición de salida, se tendrá un bucle infinito resultando en un error.